# Create and Delete cookies for external websites on their subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

Set Cookie function in Jquery

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieExpireDays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (cookieExpireDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";" + expires + ";" + "path=/";
    }
```

Delete function in Jquery

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
    var domain = location.hostname,
        path = '/'; // root path

    document.cookie = [
        name, '=',
        '; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString(),
        '; path=' + path,
        '; domain=' + domain
    ].join('');
}
```

This works fine for local links, but when I try to use it on external websites. I can get my document.cookie but deleteCookie function does not delete the cookie. Any ideas?

*Please remember, I am just running these scripts from console of Google Chrome

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't set or delete cookies for external websites. Seems like a major security risk.

Comment: I can set document.cookie. I can see those cookies in
console.log(document.cookie)
I am running the scripts from google chrome console

Comment: Well your edit changes things. You added "Please remember I'm running this in console" without ever mentioning it previously.

Comment: Sorry about it, I did edit after getting your comment. Thanks
Any ideas to delete those cookies from console?

Comment: You're about to delete your own browser cookies for a specific website?

Comment: Yeah, something like that
I am trying to delete cookie that I set for that specific website

Comment: What is the cookie you're trying to delete? Some cookies are labelled "HTTP-only" and cannot be accessed/edited using javascript. When using chrome, look in `Application->Cookies` for a list of all cookies. Those with HTTP checked cannot be modified programatically.

Comment: @tcooc Those are not HTTP. I added them to document.cookie using my setcookie Fucntion

Comment: Have you refreshed after deleting the cookie? I believe you will need to. By the way, none of the code you have uses jQuery.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan.. yeah man, refresh has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Close the browser/tab that it's on and reopen. Looks like Chrome, at least, makes them into "Session cookies" which means they stay present until you end the session.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan May be the link is the subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I am answering my own question because I changed few things and it works now.

```
    var domain = location.hostname

    function setCookie(cookiename, cookievalue, expiredays, domain) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expiredays=" + date.toGMTString();   
            document.cookie = cookiename+ "=" + cookievalue+ expires + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=/";
    }

function deleteCookie(cookiename, domain) {
    setCookie(cookiename, "", -1, domain);
}

deleteCookie("Cookie_Name",domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding something in your question, but here's how I handled the getting, setting, and deleting of a cookie I set.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hmvyu3L6/

```
<button class='set'>set</button>
<button class='get'>get</button>
<button class='delete'>delete</button>

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = 'expires=' + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + '; ' + expires;
  }

  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + '=',
    ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  function deleteCookie( name ) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
  }

  var value = 'hey there';

  $('.set').on('click', function() {
    setCookie('testCookie', value, 360);
  });

  $('.get').on('click', function() {
    console.log(getCookie('testCookie'));
  });

  $('.delete').on('click', function() {
    deleteCookie('testCookie');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cookies are HttpOnly, you will not be able to delete them using javascript or jquery.

Make sure your domain and path match exactly.  If they are different (e.g. `.subdomain.domain.com` instead of `.domain.com`, or `/path` instead of `/`) then the script will not affect the cookies.

Comment: Can you shed more light on this.
For example:- my domain is www.env.helinco.com (  var domain = location.hostname)
I am using path = '/'. Do I change path to something else?

Comment: Cookies have both a domain and a path.  Your browser can contain a different cookie for each and every combination of domain and path.  If you want to delete a cookie, you need to set new cookie with an expiration date in the past that matches exactly the cookie you want to delete, including its name, domain, and path.